# Boot Arguments with OpenLinuxBoot.efi

Tags: linux, boot, dual-boot, boot-loader

I'm using OpenCore on an `iMac15,5`, with the OpenLinuxBoot.efi driver to directly boot Fedora 37 with kernel 6.0.8, bypassing GRUB.

Normally, in my GRUB config, fedora would add some default boot arguments `rhgb quiet` to enable graphical boot. Can I pass those arguments to `linux` via my OpenCore configuration? Where would I enter those boot arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Following the guide at https://dortania.github.io/docs/latest/Configuration.html#additional-information, I mounted my boot partition, then edited the file in `/boot/loaders/entries/*.conf` which corresponded to my kernel version, and added `rhgb quiet` at the end of the line starting with `options`. The file looked like this in the end:

```
title Fedora 37
version 6.0.8-300.fc37.x86_64
linux /vmlinuz-6.0.8-300.fc37.x86_64
initrd /initramfs-6.0.8-300.fc37.x86_64.img
options root=UUID=11111111-cccc-22223333-444455556666 ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb quiet
grub_users $grub_users
grub_arg --unrestricted
grub_class fedora
```

When I restarted, I got my fancy graphical boot screen!

I also tried mounting my EFI partition at `/run/media/bennyp/EFI` and editing `/run/media/bennyp/EFI/EFI/OC/config.plist`, and then changing `UEFI>Drivers>Arguments` for `OpenLinuxBoot.efi` to `autoopts="root=UUID=11111111-cccc-22223333-444455556666 ro rootflags=subvol=root rhgb quiet"`. This did not appear to work when I reverted the changes to `/boot/loader/entries/*.conf`, So this remains a partial solution for now - I'll have to update my entries file for each new kernel version.